# employee multiple role relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, django, schema, psql

I have tables of Employee and Roles. In Roles model I'm storing manager details, there is manager hierarchy like Manager, AGM, DGM, and MD, I have to design my schema such a way that each employee has one manager and 5 managers will be reporting to one AGM and 5 AGM to one DGM. How to design this schema?

Any help would be appreciable. Thanx in advance.

Comment: My suggestion is to disregard the 5 to 1 rule.  If it ever changes, you might be in deep trouble.  Also, as you think this through, bear in mind that people come, go, and get promoted.

Comment: Normalize your data and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build on the commentors' suggestions.

If you use a data model like this:

[image]

In this model an employee has 0 or 1 manager and a manager has 1 to X employees.

The role lookup table has the current role for the employee.

For bonus points you could create a role history table so that you could keep track of promotion / work history. Like this:

[image]